# collection "total document size" is bigger than database "storage size"

Tags: mongodb

How come that the **storage size** of the whole mongo database is smaller than **total document size**?

**Storage size**
[image]

**Collection size**
[image]

Comment: Read here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17174/mongo-collection-size-is-larger-than-storagesize

Comment: @RahulRaj The DBA answer from 2012 you linked is describing the legacy MMAP storage engine. Modern versions of MongoDB (3.2+) default to the [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) which has significantly different performance and features (including document & index compression).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MongoDB's WiredTiger storage engine [compresses data and indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression) by default, so the database storage size on disk (which includes both collection & index data) is typically smaller than the sum of the uncompressed document sizes and index sizes reported in collection stats.

The ratio of storage to uncompressed data size will vary depending on factors such as how compressible your data is, the number and type of indexes you create, whether you have deleted a significant number of documents (creating free space which is available for reuse), and any configuration changes from the default server or collection options.

In your example, you have a total of about 273.5 MB of data & indexes in this database using 70.9 MB of disk storage.